# Derivation of the Leibniz (product) rule for differentiating Grassman numbers

Tags: derivatives

In Chapter 1 of Nakahara's *Geometry, Topology, Physics*, Grassman numbers are defined as linear combinations of objects $\theta_i$ which satisfy anti-commutation relations $\{ \theta_i, \theta_j\} = 0$.  Then differentiation with respect to these $\theta_i$ variables is introduced, and is stated to follow these two rules:

1. $\frac{d}{d\theta_i}\theta_j = \delta_{ij}$
2. "It is also assumed that the differential operator anti-commutes with $\theta_k$."  My reading of this is that for any given element $f$ of the Grassman algebra, the following holds: $\frac{d}{d\theta_i}(\theta_k\times f) + \theta_k \times \frac{d}{d\theta_i} f = 0$

Nakahara then writes "The Leibnitz rule then takes the form

$\frac{d}{d\theta_i}(\theta_j \theta_k) = \frac{d\theta_j}{d\theta_i}\theta_k - \theta_j\frac{d\theta_k}{d\theta_i}$,"

but I don't see how this follows from the previous two rules.  Naively, I would think that I could evaluate $\frac{d}{d\theta_i}(\theta_j \theta_k)$ by letting $\theta_k$ play the role of the function $f$ in rule (2) above, and letting $\theta_j$ play the role of $\theta_k$.  Explicitly, from rule (2) we know that

$\frac{d}{d\theta_i}(\theta_k\times f) + \theta_k \times \frac{d}{d\theta_i} f = 0$

Then making the substitution $j\rightarrow k$ gives

$\frac{d}{d\theta_i}(\theta_j\times f) + \theta_j \times \frac{d}{d\theta_i} f = 0$

Then since $f$ is any function, let $f = \theta_k$, so we have

$\frac{d}{d\theta_i}(\theta_j\times \theta_k) + \theta_j \times \frac{d}{d\theta_i} \theta_k = 0$

So

$\frac{d}{d\theta_i}(\theta_j\times \theta_k) = - \theta_j \times \frac{d}{d\theta_i} \theta_k$

Please help me understand where that derivation goes wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: You lost a kronecker delta term in 2. That will yield the result. When you rewrite the kronecker delta term and move it to the LHS.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I didn't realize that when the book says "the differential operator anti-commutes with the Grassman variable", it means that $\frac{d}{d\theta_i}(\theta_k\times f) + \theta_k \times \frac{d}{d\theta_i} f = \delta_{ik}$.